# How to add new node replica to Elasticsearch is running, without to retart service?

Tags: elasticsearch

My cluster has a yellow health as it has only one single node, so the replicas remain unasigned simply because no other node is available to contain them.

[image]

I'am readed help in [homepage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html):

[image: help in homepage]

I try add new node-data to my cluster, but it not appear when i check health's cluster.

[image]

This is config new node:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: node-data-1
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.ml: false
http.port: 9201
```

Old config, i don't edit. It's default.

Can someone explain me which files do I've to edit and what commands do I've to launch in order to create another node in my cluster? Do I've to run two ES instance? How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any indexes in the cluster? Do you have enough disk space available in the machine? What is the value for `number_of_replicas`? These three factors will make your cluster yellow. I can answer your question if you can give more details about the cluster and indices. Node need to be `master =true`, `data = true`.

Comment: No, I want to add a new node to my cluster. It doesn't join the cluster, though I have it installed as you said. I followed the answer below, and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to remove the /data folder from each Elasticsearch install before executing the nodes. Also, in the nodes that won't be the master set the following property:

`cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["machine_running_master"]`

Comment: When I delete this data, can I run it again?

Comment: Thanks @ricardo-ferreira, 
I just deleted the data directory, it joined the cluster.